# Object reference not set to an instance of an object Exception when closing my form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nullreferenceexception

When I want to close my form, the `cmbProspecten_SelectedIndexChanged` method gets recalled. But the values in cmbProspecten are null and so I get the

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Any idea about how i could solve this problem? 
I get the error message at the line: `"if(setInMail(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]), Convert.ToInt32(cmbProspecten.SelectedValue.ToString())) == true)`

```
    private void cmbProspecten_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstOntvangen.Items.Clear();

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connstring);
        string query = "SELECT Ontwikkeldossier.OntwikkeldossierID, [E-mailcampagne].CampagneID FROM [E-mailcampagne], Ontwikkeldossier WHERE (([Ontwikkeldossier].[Startdatum]>=[E-mailcampagne].[StartdatumOpl] And [Ontwikkeldossier].[Startdatum]<=[E-mailcampagne].[EinddatumOpl])) ORDER BY [E-mailcampagne].Naam";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(ds);
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        con.Close();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            EmailMarketingDataset._E_mailcampagneRow emailrow = emailMarketingDataSet._E_mailcampagne.FindByCampagneID(Convert.ToInt32(dr[1]));
            EmailMarketingDataset.OntwikkeldossierRow ontwikkelrow = emailMarketingDataSet.Ontwikkeldossier.FindByOntwikkeldossierID(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]));
            if (i != 0)
            {
                if (lstOntvangen.Items[i - 1].ToString() == emailrow.Naam)
                {
                    if(setInMail(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),Convert.ToInt32(cmbProspecten.SelectedValue.ToString())) == true)
                        lstOntvangen.Items.Add(ontwikkelrow.Titel);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (setInMail(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]), Convert.ToInt32(cmbProspecten.SelectedValue.ToString())) == true)
                    {
                        lstOntvangen.Items.Add(" ");
                        lstOntvangen.Items.Add(emailrow.Naam);
                        lstOntvangen.Items.Add(ontwikkelrow.Titel);
                    }
                    i = lstOntvangen.Items.Count - 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (setInMail(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]), Convert.ToInt32((cmbProspecten.SelectedValue.ToString())) == true)
                {
                    lstOntvangen.Items.Add(emailrow.Naam);
                    lstOntvangen.Items.Add(ontwikkelrow.Titel);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On form_onclosing event add `cmbProspecten.SelectedIndex = -1`

And Add in the selectedindexchanged event like this ..

```
private void cmbProspecten_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if cmbProspecten.selectedindex=-1 {return ;}
    lstOntvangen.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite a common problem. You find that some UI event is being raised as a form is being closed, which causes problems because things have been partially disposed or cleaned up before your handler runs.

Sometimes you can fix this by introducing a boolean `isDisposing` field and setting it to `true` at the beginning of your `Dispose()` method.

Then inside your handler, at the start of it do an early return if `isDisposing` is true.

Alternatively you can add a boolean `isClosing` field and override [`Form.OnFormClosing()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosing.aspx) and set `isClosing` to true inside your override.

Then you can do an early return from the failing handler if `isClosing` is true.

Comment: What do you mean with "Do an early return"?

Comment: @CharlotteVancraeynest I mean putting the following kind of thing at the start of the method: `if (isClosing) return;`

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't understand it. I'm a student Business & IT and I have only a basic knowledge of programming.

Comment: @CharlotteVancraeynest You mean you don't understand what `if (isClosing) return;` means inside a method?

Comment: It's OK, the answer of @matzone worked. Thanks anyway for your time to help me!